# Magento2 Installation Error help

Tags: database, error, installation, macbook

Hello I have Downloaded `MAMP` and Magento using but Can't INSTALL!

First I used this download magento,

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.0 .
```

(I have php version 7.2)

My problem comes from Magento installation protocol, first the setup/landing page is missing.

I have tried command line and I receive parameter validation, and "the sever requested authentication unknown to client errors.

It sounds like I need to make a database? my magento2 folder is in **/applications/htdocs/magento2**.

Is that where I will attach or save my db? If so how can I create a blank one using the terminal on mac? If i need it.

I used tried using this command to install

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=root --db-password=root@123 \
--admin-firstname=first --admin-lastname=last --admin-email=abc@gmail.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123
```

However I receive this error **https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsLW5.jpg**

.

I'm on MacOS... any help getting started would be WELCOMED and GREATLY appreciated!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create database from the terminal on MAC running MAMP with these steps

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your password at the prompt to connect to mysql. When connected to MySQL shell, run the code below to create your database.

```
create database magento;
exit;
```

Run the magento installation script again